# SQL Query to Select Dates (in varchar) greater than 01-01-2023

Tags: mysql

very new to SQL.. Trying to understand more.
I did not create this DB, nor do I have the ability to adjust it.
I understand dates should be changed to the proper format and not varchar..
Dates are stored as MM-DD-YYYY (110 format)

I've tried quite a few things and I cannot figure out how to convert to pull the data I need..

I am using MySQL

Any help would be appreciated.
Some attempts below.

This attempt I get error 1064 - error in SQL syntax; line 3

```
SELECT *
FROM sobacklog_all
WHERE CONVERT (DATE, Schedule_Date, 110) 
> '2023-01-01';
```

''''''''''''''''''''''
this attempt I get error 1064 at line 6

```
Select
*
From
sobacklog_all
Where
sobacklog_all.Schedule_Date >= CONVERT(DATETIME, '01-01-2023' )
;
```

Comment: sql server and mysql are two totally different products, which is this?

Comment: You must convert the column value, not referential literal.

Comment: please, when showing your attempts (which you should always do, thanks) also say what happened (give the error message, or explain what was selected that shouldn't have been or vice versa)

Comment: See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html for MySQL date/time functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In mysql:

```
SELECT *
FROM sobacklog_all
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(Schedule_Date, '%m-%d-%Y') > '2023-01-01'
```

Note that this will be unable to use an index on Schedule_Date well; you should convert your data to a date or datetime field and use that.

Comment: that's perfect, thank you! I was reading the comments above, and was researching the Str_to_date function!

http://www.sqlines.com/mysql/functions/str_to_date

Comment: strongly suggest you stick to the official mysql documentation: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date